# Why my this codes make no effect of increasing the spaces between the edges and the borders

Tags: spacing, margins

I want to increase the values of delta X and delta Y of the below image.
[image]

And I've written the below codes to achieve it.However my adjustments of  `\pdfpagewidth,\pdfpageheight` has made no effect.

The problem which is triggered from it is that as looking the pdf file or the png file,the horizontal wires of the circuit are too near to the end of the area of the content of the file so it is hard to recognize that there are wires.

What I've missing?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}
\pdfpagewidth=250mm 
\pdfpageheight=350mm 

\tikzset{voltage dir=RP}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
   \draw (0,0) to[battery1] (0,3) -- (2,3)
   to[R] (2,0) -- (0,0);
   \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The horizontal wires are too near to the end of the area of the content of the file.

Comment: yes, but that is unrelated to `circuitikz`. Any figure or content will do the same with the `standalone` class --- it has been written *just for this*.

Comment: I see.I deleted the tag of circuitikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `standalone` does not follow the page --- it's a standalone figure! You have to use the `border` option.

```latex
\documentclass[border=2cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{voltage dir=RP}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[]
   \draw (0,0) to[battery1] (0,3) -- (2,3)
   to[R] (2,0) -- (0,0);
   \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

You can also have asymmetric borders, see the documentation of the standalone package: https://ctan.org/pkg/standalone?lang=en